# Magento 2.2 Grunt Less Compile

Tags: magento

i have problem with compile less file.

In grunt config file themes.js i added

```
<theme>: {
    area: 'frontend',
    name: '<Vendor>/<theme>',
    locale: 'de_DE',
    files: [
        'css/styles-m',
        'css/styles-l'
    ],
    dsl: 'less'
}
```

and when i use commend

```
grunt less:<theme>
```

i get

```
Destination pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/de_DE/css/styles-m.css not written because no source files were found.
```

I have _theme.less in folder web/css/source.

When i try make deploy it doesnt make file _theme.less in pub/static.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have / did you actually insert the names of the vendor and theme? The error message includes / so I think what you posted above is literally what you put in the themes.js file.
And that is why it can't find those files.

Answer (score 0):

If any error when using the **grunt less** command then first Execute the command.

```
grunt exec : pub/static/frontend
```

Then use command

```
grunt less : <theme>
```